# Compact regular expression to parse days

Tags: java, regex

I need to use regular expressions to parse: "Days:1,3,5".
All days must be extracted in separate groups. I came up with the following expression:

```
"Days:(\d?)[,]?(\d?)[,]?(\d?)[,]?(\d?)[,]?(\d?)[,]?(\d?)[,]?(\d?)[,]?"
```

The problem is that there are potentially 31 days on the string.
Is there a more compact way to rewrite this regular expression?

Comment: Cant you just do [0-9+] that will match all the numbers?

Comment: Are you alway going to have 3 dates ? could it be like `Days:11,12,31,6` ?

Comment: Must first verify that string starts with "Days:" and then the number of days in the string is variable and could go up to 31. All days will be separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
Days:(\d+)|(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH5fS9/1)**

Then, in group 1 you get the first day and in group 2 you get the other days.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this doc for the chapter Groups and capturing:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg

There will be no more groups than you defined. Doesn't matter how long your input is.
I recommend you to use .split(",") to put it into an Array.